# How to install the new apk file without uninstall the old apk file on an Android device?

Tags: android

My apk file size is 2MB. First time installing the apk file in the device there is no problem.
Suppose some changes in the application after that generated the new apk file. I am try to install the new apk file in the same device then it shows some message first uninstall the previous one(i.e. , same application) in the device. But small apk files, I am not facing this problem.

Is it possible to install the new apk file without uninstall the old one?

Comment: Do you mean you installed a new apk over the previous one without uninstall, when the size was smaller? I quite doubt it depends on size; rather, I would think it's because 'android:versionCode' and being in the same package (in the manifest)

Comment: ya exactly.But apk size(in KB's) is small means i am not facing any problem. otherwise i am getting uninstall problem.

Comment: @naresh: As I know, you cannot install two different apps having same package name. You have to first uninstall the previous one.

Comment: but small application i am not getting any problem. why?

Comment: @naresh: What exactly do you mean by `small application`?

Comment: for example, the application have only one list view. the list view contains names only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not connected with apk size but with the fact that the old apk was signed with different key than the new one. So you must uninstall it before installing new application but you will have to do it only once.

Comment: it means if u want to install the new apk file then first uninstall the previous one is a manadatory. is it correct?

Comment: and more thing for small applications i am not facing uninstall problem. why?

Comment: I think that the error is because you were using different SDK (for example different computer) to install 2MB application. As a result, it is signed with different debug key than the new version you want to install. Android says that it must be unistalled before installing the new version. However, after doing that, Eclipse will automatically reinstall new versions if any other changes are done.

Comment: different SDK means different emulators(like version 2.1,2.2..) or different android devices(samsung)?

Comment: When you install android SDK, the installer creates debug.keystore file, which contains a private key which is used to sign applications when you debug them. When you reinstall SDK or use the one from different computer, OS, etc. debug.keystore is different. When application is already installed and you try to install new version, during installation Android OS checks if keys are the same. If not you get an error that keys are different and that you have to uninstall the application before installing new version.

Comment: It means the same scenario is done for small applications also but we are not getting uninstall problem why?

Comment: I mean that you could have installed 2MB apk using different SDK and now you are trying to install it using different one. However, when you are installing smaller apks you are not changing SDK and they install fine. In my opinion size of apk is not the case.

Comment: i developed the application using eclipse with android sdk after completion of application i am coping the apk file from the bin and paste it into the device(samsung) download options. Here i am using the same sdk.

Comment: Then my answer is wrong. Can you add exact message you get when you try to install 2MB apk?

Answer (score 3):

Use this command in command prompt:
adb install -r yourapplicationname.apk

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the Low Internal Memory size. Uninstall applications that are not useful. Try it after that. If u don't want to uninstall any application then you can install your APK file directly to the SD Card. Because of that your problem is solve.

I give you the hint how to Install APK on SD Card..

First create Emulator with SD Card Support and SD Card size - 1024 MiB.

After that U can Install your apk file on to sd card directly using command prompt.

Type below code in command prompt to install:

```
adb install -s name.apk
```

Comment: before insert the above cmd command.which path i am getting in the cmd. it is clear to u?

Comment: how to create emulator with sd card support?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the package name of your application otherwise it is not possible to install two applications with same package name and different keys.