# Issue while installing Android APK from Gmail directly?

Tags: android

I had installed my android APK file previously but When I did certain changes in application and I had mailed the new version of APK file to my Gmail Account but when I install new version of APK from my Gmail account directly without downloading the APK file,It is asking to uninstall the older version of APK first, I searched in many ways why this is happening but I didn't any reason, please help in this issue?

Comment: this post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531769/how-to-install-the-new-apk-file-without-uninstall-the-old-apk-file-on-an-android

Comment: Thank's for your reply Giru Bhai, But I couldn't see my issue in all android devices I am using HTC desire X with 4.0.1 version, it is working fine but when do same procedure with HTC one with 4.2.2 version the issue is comming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot possibly install two applications with the same name and references. You need to replace the older one with this one.

You can use Xposed Modules to make changes. If someone has not made any change in Xposed, you can create one yourself.

Also remember to sign the apk once and when you make a change.

Also I doubt that you cannot install a application directly from the mail account. You either need to use Google Play or copy that apk to local directory and install.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is because in gmail directly install app without download apk to any storage so when you click on install app then it is check for package if previous install or not if not then direclty install apk and if package available then check its signature if same signature available then check apk version and if version same available then it display dialog to remove first previous apk or just increment your app version code in menifest.xml file or so just Uninstall previous apk and install new one. thats it...